# End-to-End Guide line for managing a Scrum 1.0 template in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, scrum

I want to follow Agile methodology and scrum process in my project.I referred web sites and created a product back log items and started to create sprint backlogs.

Here I stuck up, since before that need to have release plan. So how could i create release plan in TFS 2010. But the Web Search is not providing the end-to-end process for the Scrum 1.0 template.

Can Any one guide me to proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

- Start with Richard Hundhausen's [Visual Studio 2010 Scrum 1.0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEgy4GEFrS8)
  webinar.   It pretty much covers the essentials.
- Fill the gaps by following guides published on blog posts. [Brian
  Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/06/07/a-scrum-process-template-for-tfs.aspx) and [Aaron Bjork](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronbjork/archive/2010/07/19/announcing-microsoft-visual-studio-scrum-1-0.aspx) are good starting points.
- Microsoft's [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/scrum) host some resourceful webcasts.
- Review the official documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731587.aspx).